# VSC use the CTRL+P to quick open file, but some file can't found

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSC use the CTRL+P to quick open file, but some file can't found.
This behavior only happy on new VSC.
The old one didn't see this.

I open the Git data base then use the VSC to open.
When I type Ctril+P can quick found the file by input the file name.
But At new VSC it can't found file at Build folder.

But I can found it at Left side the Expolrer file list.
Did I miss some thing need do open this function?

Answer (score 9):

```json
"search.useIgnoreFiles": false,
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_quick-open-applies-gitignore-exclusions