# Visual Studio Code: quick open is ignoring /vendor folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

Only since recently the quick open feature has started ignoring files in the /vendor folder.

I've looked at the `search.exclude` setting and the vendor folder isn't in there.

This has only started happening since an update in the past month or so, does the search.exclude also inherit from .gitignore?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091505/vsc-use-the-ctrlp-to-quick-open-file-but-some-file-cant-found